# is it possible to convert statement result to List<Object> in java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I want to convert the below statement result to list of my object.

```
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ExecuteStatementResult;

ExecuteStatementResult executeStatementResult = dynamoDB.executeStatement(executeStatementRequest);
System.out.println( executeStatementResult.getItems() );
```

Output:

```
[{bookingClasses={S: A,B,C,}, suppliers={S: BA,1A,TF,}, adjustmentType={S: PERCENTAGE,}, departureStartDate={S: 2022-11-17,}}]
```

Please note .getItems() method is like below:

```
public java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, AttributeValue>> getItems() {
    return items;
}
```

I want something like this to work for me:

```
List<java.util.Map<String, AttributeValue>> items =  executeStatementResult.getItems();

List<PricingRule> pricingRules = ( List<PricingRule> ) items;
```

Any help suggestion or workaround appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: @RobertHarvey please check edited question, I have defined how does getItems() method looks like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution and posting if someone may come up with this problem in future.

```
public List<PricingRule> statementToList() {

    List<PricingRule> pricingRules = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Create ExecuteStatementRequest
        ExecuteStatementRequest executeStatementRequest = createExecuteStatementRequest();
        ExecuteStatementResult executeStatementResult = dynamoDB.executeStatement(executeStatementRequest);

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        executeStatementResult.getItems().forEach(item -> pricingRules.add(mapper.convertValue(ItemUtils.toSimpleMapValue(item), PricingRule.class)));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        handleExecuteStatementErrors(e);
    }

    return pricingRules;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast directly so you will need to implement something like `PricingRule::fromMap` and do something like

```
class PricingRule {
    // everything you already have
    public static PricingRule fromMap(Map<String, AttributeValue> items) {
        // create PricingRule
    }
}
```

Then when you need your list you can use something like

```
List<java.util.Map<String, AttributeValue>> items =  executeStatementResult.getItems();

// assumes java 17+, alternatively use .collect(Collectors.toList())
List<PricingRule> pricingRules = items.stream().map(PricingRule::fromMap).toList();
```

Comment: I am using jdk8, 'cannot resolve symbol 'from' )

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `fromMap`. Do you have the `fromMap` implementation?

Comment: fromMap implementation I do not have.

Comment: I am not getting that how should fromMap implementation look like. Please consider that all fields in PricingRule class are string variable.

Comment: I don't know how `PricingRule` is constructed or what `AttibuteValue` looks like, presumably it's an AWS api class?

Comment: `PricingRule` class is my class with all string variables. And `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue` is aws class.

Comment: cannot resolve symbol `'toList()'` on below line: `List<PricingRule> pricingRules = items.stream().map(PricingRule::fromMap).toList();`

Comment: See my comment about java17 vs older version. Use `.collect(Collectors.toList())`

Comment: executeStatementResult.getItems().collect(Collectors.toList())  did not work

Comment: You still need the `.stream().map(...)` sections

Answer (score 1):

Glad you managed to solve your problem, but have you considered using the table resource?

```java
var table = dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table("TableName", TableSchema.fromClass(PricingRule.class));
List<PricingRule> items = table.query(<condition>).items().stream().toList();
```

This code requires that PricingRule is defined as a dynamo bean, for example

```java
@DynamoDbBean
public class PricingRule {
    private String pk;
    private String sk;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;

    public PricingRule() {
        
    }

    @DynamoDbPartitionKey
    public String getPk() {
        return pk;
    }

    public void setPk(String pk) {
        this.pk = pk;
    }
    
    @DynamoDbSortKey
    public String getSk() {
        return sk;
    }

    public void setSk(String sk) {
        this.sk = sk;
    }

    public String getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String field1) {
        this.field1 = field1;
    }

    public String getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String field2) {
        this.field2 = field2;
    }
}
```